# How to set the log4j level for a single Maven plugin execution?

Tags: maven, log4j, maven-plugin

I'm using the Maven -assembly-plugin and getting tons & tons of INFO messages listing all the duplicate entries being ommitted.  Is there a way to set the log4j level to "WARN" for this single plugin execution?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../package/lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

e.g. notice the duplications in the following sample of the log4j output for this step:

```
...
[INFO] META-INF/notice.txt already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/spring.handlers already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/spring.schemas already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/spring.tooling already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/INDEX.LIST already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/license.txt already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/notice.txt already added, skipping
[INFO] overview.html already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/INDEX.LIST already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/license.txt already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/notice.txt already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/spring.handlers already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/spring.schemas already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/spring.tooling already added, skipping 
...
```

In my case I have approx 3,000 of these [INFO] messages. This bloats the Maven build output and makes it much harder to see bona fide errors.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Seems impossible if you're using Maven 2.x, see [this](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-Plugin-LogLevel-td116575.html).

You can add parameter '-q' or '--quiet' to make Maven to show only error, but it's a global option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer using log4j but you can correct your problem using the next version of the assembly-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</plugin>
```